# Throw a biased coin $N+1$ times vs $N$ times

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I throw a biased coin ($P$ probability for heads) $N+1$ times and you throw it $N$ times, what is the probability that I get more heads than you?

What if I throw it $N+2$ times instead of $N+1$?

Comment: Where are you having trouble?  Simplifying a formula?  If so, what formula?

Comment: It's gonna be nasty. If $X_N$ is the total number of heads after you toss $N$ times, then you are going to get $$\sum_{k=1}^{N+1} P(X_{N+1}=k)P(X_N<k).$$ But, while $$P(X_{N+1}=k)=\binom{N+1}{k}p^k(1-p)^{N+1-k}$$ has a closed form, $P(X_N<k)$ only has a sum form, $$P(X_N<k)=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{N}{j}p^j(1-p)^{N-j}$$ which can't be simplified.

Comment: There are 2 cases: I have more Heads, or I have more tails. For $p=1/2$ these two events are of equal probability, thus $P(more Heads) = 1/2$. 

I'm trying to find out: 
1) What happens if I throw N+2 times instead of N+1, while you still throw N
and
2) What happens for other $p$, and how the above reasoning changes

Answer (score 3):

Note: @ThomasAndrews gave a correct solution in the comments of the main post.  His solution involves a double summation, while mine below only involves one or two single summation(s), and also attempts to highlight the symmetry aspect.  However, I don't know how to turn any of them into a closed form.

First, the case when A throws $N+1$ coins vs B throws $N$ coins:

Suppose B goes first, then A goes, and A temporarily stops after $N$ coins.  Three things can happen:

- Event $E=$ they have the same number of Heads.  $P(E)$ can be calculated as a single summation, summing over them each getting $k$ Heads, for $0 \le k \le N$, i.e.

$$P(E) = \sum_{k=0}^N \bigl( {N \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{N-k} \bigr)^2 $$

- Event $F=$ A has more Heads
- Event $G=$ B has more Heads
- By symmetry, $P(F)=P(G) = {1 - P(E) \over 2}$

The overall answer is $P(F) + p \times P(E) = \frac12 + P(E) (p - \frac12)$.  I don't see a closed form for $P(E)$, but I'm not sure.

---

Generalizing to the $N+2$ case requires one more single summation, to keep track of event that B has exactly one more Head.

Again, suppose B goes first, and A temporarily stops after $N$ coins.  Five things can happen:

- Event $E=$ they have the same number of Heads.  $P(E)$ given above.

  - In this event, A can win if he throws at least $1$ more Head, prob $(1 - (1-p)^2)$
- Event $F_1 = $ A has exactly $1$ more Head.
- Event $F_2 = $ A has at least $2$ more Heads (i.e. $2$ more, or $3$ more, or... compared to B).
- Event $G_1 = $ B has exactly $1$ more Head.

  - In this event, A can win if he throws Heads in his last $2$ throws, prob $p^2$.
- Event $G_2 = $ B has at least $2$ more Heads.
- By symmetry, $P(F_1) = P(G_1)$, and by explicit counting:

$$P(F_1) = P(G_1) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} {N \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{N-k}  {N \choose k+1} p^{k+1} (1-p)^{N-(k+1)}$$

- By symmetry, $P(F_2)=P(G_2) = {1 - P(E) - P(F_1)-P(G_1) \over 2}$

The overall answer is

$$P(F_2) + P(F_1) + P(E)(1 - (1-p)^2) + P(G_1) p^2 = \frac12 + P(E)(\frac12 - (1-p)^2) + P(G_1) p^2$$